# OverFlow error with Pandas series.apply

Tags: python, pandas, integer-division

I have a function that works fine with individual values, but when I use it with pandas series.apply(), it gives an OverflowError.

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

birthdays = pd.DataFrame(np.empty([365,2]), columns = ['k','probability'], index = range(1,366))
birthdays['k'] = birthdays.index
```

I make a function:

```
def probability_of_shared_bday(k):
    end_point = 366 - k
    numerator = 1
    for i in range(end_point, 366):
        numerator = numerator*i
    denominator = 365**k
    probability_of_no_match = (1 - numerator/denominator)
    return probability_of_no_match
```

when I try this out with individual integers, it works fine:

```
 probability_of_shared_bday(1)
```

0.0

```
 probability_of_shared_bday(100)
```

0.9999996927510721

But when I try and use this function with apply:

```
birthdays['probability'] = birthdays['k'].apply(probability_of_shared_bday, convert_dtype=False)
```

OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float

This happens regardless of if `convert_dtype` is True or False.

Checking `birthdays['k'].dtypes` I get `dtype('int64')`

Comment: What is `birthdays['k'].max()` ?

Comment: birthdays['k'].max() is 365

Comment: It's an intriguing problem, but honestly you should just rewrite your function to divide by 365 as you go inside the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Ian - can you give an example please?

Comment: Actually I just made it an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have this problem with `apply`, but you should not write the function like you did in the first place. Here is a suggestion that avoids dividing two huge numbers one by another:

```
def probability_of_shared_bday(k):
    end_point = 366 - k
    ratio = 1
    for i in range(end_point, 366):
        ratio *= i / 365
    probability_of_no_match = (1 - ratio)
    return probability_of_no_match
```

And the problem goes away!

Comment: That is a better way of writing the function, thanks. Would be nice to know why pandas is doing that though ;)